# Linear transformations / operators

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T : V \rightarrow V $ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$:

(a) Give an example of an operator $ T: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2 $ such that $R(T) ∩ N(T) = \{0\} $ but $T$ is not a projection

(b) Find a formula for a linear operator $ T: \mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3 $ over $C$ such that $T$ is a projection with
$R(T) = span \{(1,1,1)\}$
and
$N(T) = span \{(1,1,0) ; (0,1,1)\}$

I know that if $T$ is a projection, then $T^2 = T$, but I don't know how to create one where $R(T) ∩ N(T) = \{0\}$. 
As for (b), I try setting $T(1,1,0) = (0,0,0)$ and $T(0,1,1) = (0,0,0)$ but I'm not sure if this is correct or what to do afterwards.

$R(T)$ is the range of $T$ (I think it is also the image), $N(T)$ is the null space or kernel of $T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.**

a. $$T =\begin{pmatrix}
                 \ 2 & 0\\
                 0 & \frac{1}{2}
                 \end{pmatrix}$$

b. The matrix of $T$ in the basis $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ represented by the vectors $$P=\begin{pmatrix}
                 1 & 1 & 0\\
                 1 & 1 & 1\\
                 1 & 0 & 1
                 \end{pmatrix}$$ is $$T^\prime=\begin{pmatrix}
                 1 & 0 & 0\\
                 0 & 0 & 0\\
                 0 & 0 & 0
                 \end{pmatrix}$$ then use formula for [change of basis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) to get $T=P T^\prime P^{-1}$.

Comment: For (a), would that matrix be considered as being complex? Would it satisfy : $ T: C^2 \rightarrow C^2 ?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean for (b)? I don't understand how you obtained the matrix of T? If you use the first matrix then the null space would not have dimensions required, and if you use the second matrix then the null space would not span the required vectors. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: All matrices are real matrices. For (b) a projection is equal to zero on its kernel and to the identity on its range. This is the reason why you have the matrix I provided BEFORE the change of basis.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I just don't understand exactly how to apply the change of basis im this situation and I don't understand how that will lead to the linear operator T required?

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: The fact that the range is the span of (1,1,1) means that the output in all three columns should be the same right? I attempted calculating PTP^−1 and got a matrix with (1,-1,1) for all three rows. I can see that T(1,1,0) and T(0,1,1) would both give (0,0,0) i.e the kernel, but does this conform with the range constraint? I apologize if I seem a bit clueless about this all

Comment: The fact that the range is $\mathbf{span}\{(1,1,1)\}$ means that each colum vector of the projection matrix should be a multiple of $(1,1,1)$ which is what you found. And as the kernel is also good... You're done!

Comment: I know that I am supposed to avoid comments like thanks, but thanks! I appreciate your input and I also appreciate that you helped me through rather than just answering the question. I definitley gained a better understanding

Comment: You're welcome!